# Set transition for specific property in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom, properties, transition, translate

I am using transition(0.3s) in CSS when hover some texts for changing the color, but I also used transition in Javascript for "translate" the text. My problem now is that, when I hover them, they don't use anymore the transition in CSS (0.3s) but what I set in javascript. I tried using element.style.transition = "translate 5.4s ease" or in css I set delay for specific property but in vain.How can i set the transition in Js only for translate? Thank you in advance

CSS

```
social-media-texts p {
   position:relative;
   color:white;
   font-size:20px;
   transition: opacity 0.3s;
   transform: translate(-300%);
   opacity: 0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
socialTexts.forEach((element) => {
  element.style.opacity = "1";
  element.style.transform = "translate(0)";
  element.style.transition = 1.1 * countP + "s";
  countP += 0.3;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are overwriting the previous transition property. You would need to expand it by adding a comma followed by your new transition (eg. transform 1.1s)

That would result in the following property: `transition: opacity 0.3s, transform: 1.1s;`

See section **Change Several Property Values**: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp